# Scala Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines().next() пропускает второй символ в строке

Tags: файлы, scala, итераторы

Вот этот код:

```
val bufferedSource = Source.fromFile(fileName)
val lines = bufferedSource.getLines()
bufferedSource.close()
println(lines.next())
```

Для содержимого файла build.sbt:

```
name := "timeSeriesMerge"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
```

Выводит следующую строку:

```
"nme := "timeSeriesMerge""
```

Тоесть второй символ этой строки пропал. Кто нибудь подскажет в чем проблема? Оно пропускает второй символ только для первой строки. Для всех последующих строк не пропускает

Comment: В какой оболочке запускаете код?
Попробовал в IntelliJ и в Ammonite - и там и там работает корректно

Comment: (Странно, у меня этот код кидает `java.io.IOException: Stream Closed`.)
Попробуй поставить проблемную строку на другое место. Например пусть `version := "0.1"` будет первой.